# rx_queue_index returns always value 1 for ipv6-Srv6 packets on XDP-eBPF

Tags: nic, xdp-bpf

I am trying to keep track of `Ipv6-Srv6` packets using simple XDP-eBPF program. I get the NIC queue as always 1.

Following is environment details

1. OS: guest OS, Ubuntu 19.10, 5.3.0-64-generic
2. NIC: x710: 10Gbps, driver=i40e, driverversion=2.8.20-k, firmware=7.20
3. XDP-eBPF: my custom sample program

```
#include <bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ipv6.h>

#include <stdint.h>

#ifndef lock_xadd
#define lock_xadd(ptr, val)     ((void) __sync_fetch_and_add(ptr, val))
#endif

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") queue_rx_pkts = {
        .type        = BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY,
        .key_size    = sizeof(__u32),
        .value_size  = sizeof(__u64),
        .max_entries = 256,
};

SEC("prog")
int xdp_select(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
        //__u32 input_port = ctx->ingress_ifindex;
        __u32 input_queue = ctx->rx_queue_index;

        void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
        void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
        struct ethhdr *eth_ptr = (struct ethhdr *)data;
        struct ipv6hdr *ipv6_ptr = (struct ipv6hdr *)(data + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
        unsigned int *pkt_count = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&queue_rx_pkts, &input_queue);

        if (!pkt_count)
                return XDP_ABORTED;

        if ((data + sizeof(*eth_ptr)) > data_end)
                return XDP_DROP;


        if (eth_ptr->h_proto == 0xdd86) {
                if ((void *)(ipv6_ptr + 1) > data_end)
                        return XDP_DROP;
                *pkt_count += 1;
                return XDP_PASS;
        }

        return XDP_DROP;
}
```

- packet generator: Host NIC X710 run with packEth cli utility with `packETHcli -i ens261f2 -m 2- d 0 -n 0 -f /tmp/test.pcap`
- Expected result: Ingress packets would be spread on multiple RX queues.
- Observed result: RX queue 1 is only getting packets.

[image]

I verified the results with `ethtool -S [interface name]` and `bpftool map dump id 12`. Both cases RX-Queue-1 is only getting updated.

[image]

[EDIT-1] updating RSS hash status as per the recommendation from comment

```sh
$ ethtool --show-rxfh-indir ens10                                                                                                                                                                                                      [4/1785]
RX flow hash indirection table for ens10 with 8 RX ring(s):
    0:      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
    8:      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
<snipped>
  504:      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
RSS hash key:
9b:d2:e1:c0:f7:aa:1f:69:49:7c:55:76:48:7e:2c:fc:d5:91:47:39:df:50:52:8f:88:07:c8:63:62:27:93:17:35:75:dc:f6:85:e8:ff:c2:72:1d:de:92:d4:2b:1e:d9:f2:53:df:38
RSS hash function:
    toeplitz: on
    xor: off
    crc32: off
```

Comment: Thank you @Progman for the edit, but do you feel the C code is causing the issue?

Comment: @stackinside thank you it does make sense, can you please post it as answer. I will check the same by changing IP address and update the question as required